# Save cv::Mat to FITS image? (opencv, C++)

Tags: opencv, fits

I have an object of type [`cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) in C++ that has my image pixel data loaded.

I would like to save the resulting image as FITS format, however attempting a call to `imwrite` with a `.fits` file extension simply results in:

```
could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'imwrite_'
```

How would I go about saving an image saved in an object of type `cv::Mat` to a FITS file?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: You should choose a library here to read/write FITS files and do the conversions from/to `cv::Mat`. https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_libraries.htm

Comment: @Burak "the requested library could not be found"

Comment: https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_libraries.html